# Regex to extract first number with decimals from a string

Tags: regex

I have this below regex which I want to use to extract numbers with decimals from a string

```
 scala> val numPattern = """[0-9]+.[0-9]+|[0-9]+.[0-9]+|[0-9]+""".r
 numPattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = [0-9]+.[0-9]+|[0-9]+.[0-9]+|[0-9]+

 scala> numPattern.findFirstIn("s2s")
 res24: Option[String] = Some(2)

 scala> numPattern.findFirstIn("s2.4s")
 res25: Option[String] = Some(2.4)
```

But I want to extract .4 and .42 in these below cases.

```
 scala> numPattern.findFirstIn("s.4s")
 res26: Option[String] = Some(4)

 scala> numPattern.findFirstIn("s.42s")
 res28: Option[String] = Some(42)
```

How can I do that?

Same result with

```
scala> val numPattern="""(\d+)([.]\d+)?""".r
```

Comment: `.` is a wildcard..  first form is trivially wrong. It's also basically grammatically wrong in other ways that make me want to suggest a regex tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/J6l7srynyw).

You can’t do both optional leading *and* trailing digits without the alternation because then it would match the empty string.

Comment: `\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+`

Comment: @Billy your regex wouldn't match `"s4.s"`, mind you matching `"4"` is probably good enough, but OP isn't clear on that.

Comment: @Bohemian yeah, unclear, but my intuition is that in the case of `4.` you would want to match `4` as it seems odd to me the other way. Just checked, and `4.` is recognised as a number by javascript, I would have expected it might be syntax error :shrug: